# query by set date range forcing year based on month

Tags: sql-server, powerbi, sql-server-2016

SQL Server 2016 - PowerBI

I need to write a static query that will be used in PowerBI for dashboards that automatically update themselves that doesn't obtain any prompts that use our companies budget cycle which is July 1 - June 30.  I can pull the data easily from the tables I need it but it is the where clause that I am stuck on.  I need it to query to show me records that are only done between 7/1/{year} - 6/30/{year}.  Is there a way to query that says show me all records with dates between

(if month(getdate()) in (1,2,3,4,5,6) then '7/1/' + year(getdate())) or else if month(getdate()) in (7,8,9,10,11,12) then '7/1/' + year(dateadd(y,-1, getdate()))

and

(if month(Getdate()) in (1,2,3,4,5,6' then '6/30/' + year(getdate()) or else if month(getdate()) in (7,8,9,10,11,12) then '6/30/' + year(datediff(y,1,getdate())))month(getdate()) in (1,2,3,4,5,6) then '7/1/' + year(getdate()))

If I write that code into my query, I get an error on failure when converting the varchar value '7/1/' to data type int.  I recognize that is a problem with the / in the line and trying to attach an int value to a varchar but I can't seem to figure out how to get past that.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to cast **YEAR(GETDATE())** as **VARCHAR** first which will allow you to concatenate the string '7/1/' with the year (string) value. Now you will have a  new string like - "7/1/2020". Now cast this string again as DATE before applying other conditions. This will be something like below-

```
CAST('7/1/'+CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR) AS DATE)
```

Comment: Nice to see that it worked. You can also put an up vote if it really helped :)